# How to access nested controllers in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, module, controller, nested

I have a web application and I want to extend it to a Web API. I have split my controller into 2 folders Web, and Api. I have my ApplicationController in the Web folder and want to have a ApiController in the api folder.

I know that the ActionController is only supposed to be inherited from the ApplicationController. Is there a way that I can use 2 separate controllers so I can have different behaviour in each?

An example why I want 2 is so I can handle CanCan exceptions in different ways and protect_from_forgery with differently.

**Update**

When I try to run my tests I get the following error

> api_sessions_controller.rb:1:in `': uninitialized constant ApiController (NameError)

My Api Sessions Controller is

```
class ApiSessionsController < ApiController
    def create
        user_password = params[:session][:password]
        user_email = params[:session][:email]
        user = user_email.present? && User.find_by(email: user_email)

        if user.valid_password? user_password
          sign_in user, store: false
          user.generate_authentication_token!
          user.save
          render json: user, status: 200, location: [:api, user]
        else
          render json: { errors: "Invalid email or password" }, status: 422
        end
    end
end
```

And the Api Controller is

```
class ApiController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session

  # include SessionsHelper

  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
        if user_signed_in?
            flash[:error] = "Access denied!"
            redirect_to root_url
        else
            flash[:error] = "Please Sign in"
            redirect_to new_user_session_path
        end
    end
end
```

I'm at a loss as to what is causing this, I can't see what is wrong with either controller and this is why I thought there might have been some conflict with what I was doing and the rails framework

Comment: is there any shared logic that should be used by both controllers?

Comment: no they will both be different

Comment: Can you open `rails console test` and create a subclass of `ActionController::Base`?  Also, what are the complete filepath (including filename) of your new controllers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with ABMagil, nobody says you HAVE to inherit `ApplicationController`. In your case, you especially mention you want different access control + CSRF protections, so it's totaly justified to have another application controller that inherits from `ActionControlle::Base`

Anyway, everything will happen in your routes :

```
namespace :api do
  # Stuff here will automatically look inside controllers/api/ folder, 
  # URL prefixed with /api/ 
  # View url/path helpers with prefix api_
end
# your_domain.com/api/my_resource/

scope module: 'web' do
  # Stuff here will look for controllers in controllers/web/ 
  # NO URL prefix
  # NO url/path prefix for View helpers
end
# your_domain.com/my_resource
```

EDIT : concerning your error

When namespacing, it means you are wrapping your classes in a module, so you have to specify this for every sub-controller. i.e

- You can either have `ActionController` and `ApiController` in the `/controller/` folder (I suggest you to do this + 3rd bullet point, feels more clear)

  ```
  controllers/api_controller.rb, 
  controllers/application_controller.rb

  class ApiController, class ApplicationController
  ```
- If you want to move them to api/web subfolders, you have to reflect that in the files

  ```
  controllers/api/api_controller.rb, 
  controllers/web/application_controller.rb

  class Api::ApiController, class Web::ApplicationController
  ```
- And obviously, also respect this for your other controllers

  ```
  controllers/api/session_controller.rb

  class Api::SessionController
  ```

Also note, if you want to keep API (only capital letters), I think it works when you use folder name `/API/`

Comment: From the answers here it looks like the error I'm seeing in my tests isn't caused by inheriting from ActionController twice. I'll add more detail to my question

Comment: Thanks, I took your advice and made the changes in point 1 & 3.

Answer (score 1):

Who says only ApplicationController can/should inherit from ActionController?  [ApplicationController](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/1602a70fb450aba9b5e5befe4c7bfc3344471a06/railties/lib/rails/application_controller.rb) sets the path to view files (not relevant for APIs) and defines `require_local!` and `local_request?`.  If you don't use those methods (`require_local!` is called by `InfoController` and `MailersController`, within the Rails codebase), then you're not losing anything.

If you have logic that's only for your API, you certainly could subclass ActionController directly, but is it necessary?  If you subclass ApplicationController but override relevant methods, won't that cover your use case?

Comment: Maybe I mis-understood "By default, only the ApplicationController in a Rails application inherits from ActionController::Base. All other controllers in turn inherit from ApplicationController. This gives you one class to configure things such as request forgery protection and filtering of sensitive request parameters." from http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html

Comment: That's the rails team communicating their _intent_.  It's backed up by convention; for instance, the generator commands automatically creating controllers that inherit from ApplicationController.  BUT, it's your app, and it's just ruby so you can do anything you can code.  If you have two branches of your app, you can subclass ActionController to create the second branch, which shouldn't break anything (pending the stipulations in my answer)